# How to get angular.js module's value from another module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services, angular-module

I have two modules in my angular.js app.
In module1 (example name) I have a value defined like

```
angular.module('module1')
    .value('ID', '')
    .service('someService', function(ID) {
        this.getId = function() {
            return ID;
        }
        this.setId = function(id) {
            ID = id;
        }
    })
```

I would like to access module1's ID value in module2.
I can access module1 from module2 using 
`

```
angular.module('module1')
```

log in console will be`

```
Object {_invokeQueue: Array[39], _configBlocks: Array[1], _runBlocks: Array[1], requires: Array[8], name: "module1"}
```

when I try to access ID value or someService using

```
angular.module('module1').service("someService");
```

or

```
angular.module('module1').value("ID");
```

I am getting strange object looks like

```
Object {_invokeQueue: Array[40], _configBlocks: Array[1], _runBlocks: Array[1], requires: Array[8], name: "module1"}
```

Also I can't include module1 in the module2 on initialization, using this style

```
angular.module('module2', ['module1']);
```

because I already have module2 included in module1

```
angular.module('module1', ['module2']);
```

Comment: Does the same value of ID exist in both modules?

Comment: @MathewBerg It exist only in module1

Comment: Then you should be able to DI it into either if you've included module2 in module1.

Comment: @MathewBerg Can you explain more detailed, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to inject it as a dependency as you would with a controller or service etc.

If you wanted to access it in a controller you could have code similar to this

```
angular.module('module2').controller('MyExistingCtrl', ['ID', function(ID){
    console.log(ID);
}]);
```

Or, following John Papa's styleguide:

```
angular.module('module2').controller('MyExistingCtrl', MyExistingController)

MyExistingController.$inject = ['ID'];

function MyExistingController(ID){
    console.log(ID);
}
```

Read more on [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

Also it is explained on the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) for providers. Scroll down the "Value Recipe" section.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for answer. As I understood your code will create a new controller inside of module1  in the case I need to access 'ID' value in module2's existing controller.

Comment: @styopdev Well, that was just example syntax. Just swap the module and controller name to suit your needs. You are just injecting, the same as you inject anything else. I will edit.

Comment: It works, thanks for help! I couldn't imagine that solution is so evident and its  possible to inject other module's value in controller.

Comment: @styopdev no problem, glad to help! As long as the module is included as a dependency, you can inject all it's values, services, constants etc. anywhere. This is the basis of how third party modules work. Include the module -> get access to all services.